# What is Namespace URI Constant.NamespaceSpecNS stands for?

Tags: c#, java, xml

I'm porting parts of Java project to C# and came across this constant `Constant.NamespaceSpecNS.`

One of its uses is in the following Java context:

```
_xmlElement.setAttributeNS(Constants.NamespaceSpecNS,"a_qualified_name", "some_value");
```

where `seAttributesNS` is declared in `org.w3c.dom Interface Element`.

So, from this call, I know it is some sort of namespace uri, but that's about all I know.
Can anybody point to where this `Constant.NamespaceSpecNS` is defined? What it's actual value is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its defined as "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/" in org.apache.xml.security.utils.Constants.